# Pascal - Array argument in procedure call

Tags: arrays, procedure, freepascal

I have this code. I am trying to calculate the longest chain of domino stones i can create I have never more then 16 stones. I use array 'domino' of integer to store the nubmers on stones. When I tryed to run this program I got SIGSEGV exception on line 25(I am using Lazarus IDE v1.4.4). Probably some problem with calling of procedure. Thanks for your help.

```
var n,maxDelka:integer;
type  dominoType = array[1..16,1..2] of integer;
var   domino:dominoType;
procedure NactiDomino;
var i:integer;
begin
read(n);
 for i:=1 to n do begin
         read(domino[i][1]);
         read(domino[i][2]);
 end;
end;

procedure VynulujDomino;
var i:integer;
begin
for i:=1 to 16 do begin
         domino[i][1]:= 0;
         domino[i][2]:= 0;
                 end;
maxDelka:=0;
end;
procedure RetezezDomino(VDomino:dominoType);
var i,y :integer;
begin //------------------here was the exception---------------------------
 for i:=1 to n do begin
     for y:=1 to n do begin
          if((VDomino[i][1]=VDomino[y][1])and(VDomino[i][1]<>-1))then begin VDomino[i][1]:= -1;VDomino[y][1]:= -1; RetezezDomino(VDomino); end
     else if((VDomino[i][1]=VDomino[y][2])and(VDomino[i][1]<>-1))then begin VDomino[i][1]:= -1;VDomino[y][1]:= -1; RetezezDomino(VDomino); end
     else if((VDomino[i][2]=VDomino[y][2])and(VDomino[i][2]<>-1))then begin VDomino[i][1]:= -1;VDomino[y][1]:= -1; RetezezDomino(VDomino); end;

     end;
 end;
inc(maxDelka);
end;



begin
  VynulujDomino;
  NactiDomino;
  writeln(maxDelka);
  RetezezDomino(domino);
  writeln(maxDelka);
end.
```

Comment: Searching for bugs is all about narrowing down the problem. Your problem seems to be something within the recursion call of RetezezDomino. 

Add some debug output. E.g. write the array to console at the beginning and the end of RetezezDomino. So you can see what happens in here.
Are you sure you need recursion in your case? If yes, make sure that your program has a valid exit point and always terminates. (This is not for sure at the moment!)

You also should consider to name your functions and variables in English, which makes it easyer to get help from outside

Comment: Also try not to post code with identifiers in your native language (Hungarian, I guess ?). Always use English.

Comment: Compile using range and overflow checks on. That will give you the moment of the earliest mistake rather than its consequences (SIGSEGV). Oh and ident your code properly.